# Keras model has different losses

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, keras-layer

I am currently working on a Keras model. My goal is to have the lowest RMSE possible so I set the loss and metrics to RMSE. After the model is trained, when I calculate the RMSE of the model on the training data I get a higher result. Why is that?

My RMSE function for the model is this one:

```
from keras import backend as K
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

After the model is trained I calculate my rmse with this function

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
def measure_mse(actual, predicted):
    return  sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, predicted))

measure_mse(train_y, model.predict(train_x))
```

## ====================================================================

```
layer_in = Input(shape=(16,1))

layer_regr = GRU(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', return_sequences=True)(layer_in)

layer_regr = Dropout(0.2)(layer_regr)

layer_regr = GRU(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', return_sequences=True)(layer_regr)

layer_regr = GRU(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal')(layer_regr)

layer_regr = Dropout(0.2)(layer_regr)

layer_regr = Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal')(layer_regr)

layer_out = Dense(1,)(layer_regr)

model = Model(inputs=layer_in, outputs=layer_out)

model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer='adam', metrics=[root_mean_squared_error])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size = 16, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpointer])

model.load_weights('weights.hdf5')
```

## ====================================================================

results:

> keras model: val_root_mean_squared_error: **1.8079**
>
> I calculate: **2.1155**

Comment: `val_root_mean_squared_error` is the validation RMSE (i.e. computed on validation data). Is the reported number, i.e. 2.1155, computed on the validation data as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. I said the validation error but at the beginning, I introduced the code for the train set instead of the test set, sorry about that. I tried running it a few times, and the difference between the number computed by Keras and the number that I calculate is around 0.2 - 0.5 for both the validation set and the train set. Here is an image https://imgur.com/LaOCfaJ